# Создание нового свойства-зависимости для Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет. Мне нужна помощь в создании нового dependency property, по функциональности точно такой же как SelectedDates.

Логика работы:
SelectedDates выделяет голубым цветом, а при нажатии вверху кнопки "Установить" в новое свойство закидываем значения из SelectedDates, делаем его другим цветом и записываем значения в текстовый документ.

Так же должна быть возможность считывания из текстового документа этих дат. При повторном запуске программы установленные даты 13.05.2015, 14.05.2015, 15.05.2015 должны уже быть подсвечены.

Вот исходник http://my-files.ru/bjd0h1

[image: картинка 1] [image: картинка 2]

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: Мне кажется, то, что вам нужно — это прибиндить `SelectedDates` к вашей `DependencyProperty` в VM.

Comment: VlaD, можешь написать пример кода?

Comment: @Darkleon: `SelectedDates="{Binding YourProperty}"`?

Comment: VlaD, не получается, может я что-то не так делаю, да и не могу понять логику.